# Installing VS2015 Roslyn

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

New computer build, clean install of Win 10, installed VS2017.  After struggling with VS2017 issues for a few weeks I decided to go back to VS2015 and wait for an update.  I uninstalled 2017 without problems, but when I try to install 2015 I get a message that Roslyn Language Services can't be installed because there's already a version installed and to uninstall RLS using Add/Remove Programs in the control panel.  No such thing as Roslyn in the Apps list.

Is there another way to uninstall RLS 2017 so I can finish installing VS2015?

Comment: Being that it is a new computer build, I would recommend wiping and re-installing the whole computer.  You are guaranteed to have a clean install that way.  I know that doesn't fix the issue, but that is how I would handle it on my own computer.

Comment: That's more than a few days work to re-configure a development system.  Think I'll hang out and hope someone has an easier solution before I head down that road.  :)

Comment: Do you have a restore point from before installing VS 2017?

Comment: Possibly.  Having *never* used a restore point before, I'll have to do a little research on how they work.  Good thought, James.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error, and couldn't Repair 2015. I was able to resolve it when uninstalling an entry in "Programs and Features" titled similar to "Visual Studio for Applications 2015 Languages". I thought this was spoken/written languages, but it related to programming languages (the Roslyn service shows up in the Visual Studio dialog after clicking uninstall on that entry).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll give it a try.